# Automatically move photos to directories based on exif date

Tags: windows, file-management, photography, exif

I am using Windows. I wish to move a lot of family photos based on the EXIF data, date created or date modified.

I came across this software called PhotoMove 2.5. The software moves photos to Y>M>D while I want it to move to Y>M. The paid version the the software does what I want. But I tried to contact the owner and got no email back. So it seems like the software might be out of development.

Is there any alternative to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[DropIt](http://www.dropitproject.com/) can do that and much more. It's also open source.

[Here](http://www.dropitproject.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=howto:organize_images_by_date_and_properties) are examples of sorting/moving files by date. In your case the destination would be:

```
C:\Some\Dir\%YearTaken%\%MonthTaken%
```

You can also [automatically monitor](http://www.dropitproject.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=howto:automatically_scan_folders) some directories.
[image: Monitoring]

Comment: looks promising. But what if the image does not have a date? will it be moved or will it be moved to a special folder? what is the error handling scenario?

Comment: It won't be moved IIRC, at least how it worked in different scenario, but better to just test edge cases yourself. Not sure what kind of error scenario you're asking about or if it's the same question as the 1st one.